# tex exceeded capacity when writing simple paragraph

Tags: document-classes, article, memory, capacity

I have a very simple latex code after watching a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yybt9XhF8kQ&list=PLNmACol6lYY7f_rYxXQc50BhEwzfSpe2k&index=19)  which is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[]{tabular}
\usepackage[•]{color}
\title{Kodie Data}
\author{Kodie}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tabular}{|l| l l}
Sr no. & House Details  & City \\
1 & RRT67/P & Alaska \\
2 & OIx/Q & Boka \\
\end{tabular} \newline

This is a sentence \emph but this not \emph{emphasized}
This we do not know how it works. \textsc {But some thing is happening so we should understand.} \\
\texttt {How about you making chutiya.} \\
\textsf{aalor ja ja ja } \\
\color{red}
You can change this as \textup{well}.
\end{document}
```

when I compile this I get error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\curr@fontshape ->\f@encoding
/\f@family /\f@series /\f@shape
l.4 \title
{Kodie Data}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
221 strings out of 481556
2733 string characters out of 2906857
443030 words of memory out of 3000000
15560 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
5000i,0n,9994p,148b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What is this fatal error. Why is it coming the code is very very simple in my opinion I should not be getting any errors.
I use Windows 10 amd Miktex 2.9

Comment: Remove `[•]` from `\usepackage[•]{color}`.

Comment: I also suggest using `xcolor` instead of `color`.

Comment: oh thanks this worked.

Comment: I want to be an expert in latex let me know if you have any suggestions. How to become an expert.

Comment: what did you want `\usepackage[•]{color}` to  do?? have you seen any documentation that suggested that there was a `•` option (if so we could try to get it fixed)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my guess would be some template of an editor (mine e.g. insert such bullets for stuff that should be replaced).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree with Ulrike Fischer TeXMaker does that for instance

Comment: inserting stuff into the document that generates errors seems er,... suboptimal.  Why can't it add the bullet on its own line as a comment if it really wants to do that.

Comment: Secrets of the LaTeX Illuminatti:  Find the source code and learn to read it.  Okay, at least read all the manuals, a good LaTeX book and the TeXbook by Knuth.